# insert date to mysql with correct format inserts '0000-00-00'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, format

This question was raised a lot of times and none of them gave me the correct answer.

```
$birthday=date('d.m.Y', strtotime($_POST['birthday']));
echo "birthday: ".$birthday // prints "15.05.1998" - that's nice    
$query = "INSERT INTO teilnehmer (vorname, nachname, email, geschlecht, birthday, telefon) VALUES ('$vorname', '$nachname', '$email', '$geschlecht', '$birthday', '$telefon')";
$erfolg = mysql_query($query, $verbindungID) or die ("Beim Erstellen ist ein Fehler unterlaufen. ". mysql_error());
```

The database entry shows `0000-00-00`. Do I have to convert it to the databases format? Or how can I change the format in the database?

Comment: yes mysql its Y-m-d so u need to convert to that format.

Comment: `d.m.Y` is not as correct as you might think.

Comment: It is always a good idea to store date constants in the ISO standard format, either YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: They **ALL** give the correct answer. If you're inserting date strings into mysql, you have to use `yyyy-mm dd hh:mm:ss` format. Anything else will get trashed.

Comment: ok... at least that was never answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do `$birthday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['birthday']));`